# Read/write access to server files for Myyna

Tags: ibm-cloud

I managed to install [Myyna](http://www.myyna.com/) (an [opensource project](https://github.com/cubettech/myyna/) for social networking running on Node.js) on Bluemix.

Unfortunately, the guys at Myyna have a **one-time installation procedure** which requires to modify some files so that **read/write access is needed** for some .js files on the server.

[image]

> "Please provide read and write permission to config.js, defines.js,
>   mongodb.js in your '/application/config' folder & '/uploads' folder."

Is there a way to do that in Bluemix?? (I'm a newbie regarding Bluemix)

Thanks in advance for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file system is read only in that respect for writing files.  Wordpress has this same issue.

I would suggest creating the config file beforehand.  It might be good to modify the code a bit so you can read the `VCAP_SERVICES` env variable to get the database info.

It looks like you need to hack `application/config/config.js` a bit to read the environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

One technique I've had some success with - in situations like this - is writing a shim to invoke the original app, where the shim gets things in place so the original app can run correctly.

I have an example in my cf-fed-wiki project, in the file [app.js](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/cf-fed-wiki/blob/master/app.js).  This shim gets the credentials from a MongoDB database provisioned from within Bluemix, and then sets up the command-line parameters to reflect those credentials.  Last thing it does is to launch the start up for the original app, via `require("wiki")`.

You might have some luck with a similar approach. You may also want to ask the authors of the Myyna package to provide an option that doesn't require the one-time installation, but provides all the neccessary information via environment variables (and perhaps somehow via Cloud Foundry's VCAP_SERVICES environment variable), to make it easier to run their package on cloud hosting platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not a good practice to hard code credentials in your source, for non-production testing, you could temporarily modify these files manually before pushing.